# Finding a Mean of an Attribute for a Specific Class in Python

Tags: python, numpy, nan, mean

I'm trying to write a function to find the mean of an attribute for values that only fall within a specific class.

Below is my code:

```
`mean=0
total=0
count=0
for i in range(len(training_data)):
    if (training_data[i,334])==0:
        if training_data[i,2]<>None:
            total+=training_data[i,2]
            count+=1
    mean=total/count`
```

However, my attribute has some null values in it. I am working with numpy, and the null values are being coded as "NaN". In my function above, even though I am specifically specifying that the value cannot be equal to "None", which is Python's equivalent to null, my "total" attribute continues to show up as 'nan'. I have tried many different equivalents to "None" and have not been able to get a value for the total variable other than 'nan'. Is there something obvious I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try the `None` tests interactively; you may need to use `is None` or `is not None`.  Similarly test `nan` in small expresion first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the power of `numpy` your code can be trimmed to 2 lines:

```
idx = training_data[:,334] == 0
mean = np.nanmean(training_data[idx, 2])
```

`idx` here is the boolean array which is `True` for the indices of rows falling into specific class, and `np.nanmean` calculates the mean value ignoring NaNs.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, a numpy solution as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35619832/3005167) is preferrable to for loops.

Here, I will answer the explicit question:

> [I] have not been able to get a value for the total variable other than 'nan'. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

You cannot directly compare `nan`s. The expression `np.nan != np.nan` always results in `True` and `np.nan == np.nan` always results in `False`. In other words, *nan is not equal to itself*.

This means, if you use `==` or `!=` to check for nan the code believes the value is not nan and adds it to the result. When you add nan to anything the result is nan, which is what you get.

To correctly check if a value is nan you can use `math.isnan()` or `np.isnan()`.

**Edit:** I have assumed NaN-values were coded as `nan` in the data. Actually, this is not totally clear from the question. If they are coded as `"nan"` strings or `None` a slightly different treatment is required.